# DateAdd with abbreviation from column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have have the following SQL that increases the starttime of each row in the result from MOCKTABLE.

```
SELECT
    DATEADD( "d", ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.ID), mt.StartTime ) AS INCREMENT
FROM
    MOCKTABLE mt
```

Now I would like to trade the "d" to a column specified in MOCKTABLE. Like this:

```
SELECT
    DATEADD( mt.PeriodTime, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.ID), mt.StartTime ) AS INCREMENT
FROM
    MOCKTABLE mt
```

How can I do this? The column PeriodTime is nvarchar(5) and will contain 'd', 'ww' or 'm'. Reason I want this is because the user should decide the incrementation of the orginial date.

Comment: Can you give some examples of what values are in the PeriodTime column?

Comment: Well, for one, you shouldn't be using abbreviations at all. If you mean `DAY`, type `DAY`. Why? Well, a simple example, does `SELECT DATEPART(y, GETDATE());` return the result you expect?

Comment: @Ek0nomik, edited question. I cannot type DAY since queries will differ on requests, sometimes i want weeks and etc depending on whats been chosen on the original rows column.

Comment: I didn't mean type it, I mean store it, whatever. You shouldn't have `d` or `w` in the table, you should have `DAY` and `WEEK`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it with a big case statement:

```
SELECT (case when PeriodTime = 'day'
             then DATEADD(day, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.ID), mt.StartTime)
             when PeriodTime = 'month'
             then DATEADD(month, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.ID), mt.StartTime)
             when PeriodTime = 'year'
             then DATEADD(year, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.ID), mt.StartTime)
        end) AS INCREMENT
FROM MOCKTABLE mt
```

Comment: Why not get the row_number once, and *then* apply the dateadd? Makes the CASE expression a lot tidier. Also you have `mm` instead of `MONTH`, and the last expression uses `mm` when you meant `YEAR`.

Comment: @AaronBertrand . . . Are you suggesting putting the `row_number()` in a subquery?  SQL Server doesn't all `DATEADD((case when PeriodTime = 'day' then day . . . end), . . . )`.

Comment: I'm saying `WITH x AS (SELECT StartTime, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER ... FROM mt) SELECT CASE WHEN PeriodTime = 'day' THEN DATEADD(day, rn, StartTime) ELSE ... FROM x;`

Comment: (Just reduces the number of times you have to repeat that ROW_NUMBER() expression, that's all.)

Comment: [So out of curiosity, why do you insist on using shorthand abbreviations like `mm` instead of just spelling out `MONTH`? Is saving a couple of keystrokes worth the ambiguity and potential problems?](https://sqlblog.org/blogs/aaron_bertrand/archive/2011/09/20/bad-habits-to-kick-using-shorthand-with-date-time-operations.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't need years or months, then instead of PeriodTime being a string, it could be an int

e.g if the smallest increment you wanted to make was an hour. 1,24,168 would give you hour, day and week in

```
DateAdd(hour,PeriodTime * ROW_Number(),Somedate)
```

without the huge and irritating case statement.

Comment: I like this alternate solution solution too. Could be issues related to DayLight saving time, etc. Though it is a bit more fragile as someone is certain to change the requirements to support months once it is in production.

Comment: Months and Years are out of scope. Rewrite, and retest, estimate two weeks. :)

Comment: This is a nice solution but month will be required :)

Answer (score 0):

The quick answer is that you can't do that exactly

```
select datepart(day, getdate()) -- this works
select datepart('day', getdate()) -- this throws the following error

Msg 1023, Level 15, State 3, Line 1
Invalid parameter 1 specified for datepart.
```

I could do something like this however

```
select case 
  when mt.PeriodTime 'day' then datapart(day,getdate())
  when mt.PeriodTime 'hour' then datapart(hour,getdate())
  ...
end
```

DateAdd works the same way.

-- Looks like I lost the answer race by 34 seconds.